# Customize search result

Tags: search, entities

How can i remove `Only of the type(s)` on the advance options. and `username` and `created day` display on the footer search result?

Answer (score 1):

The [Custom Search](http://drupal.org/project/custom_search) module provides easy control over many of those search options.

Answer (score 0):

You can use template files like search-result.tpl.php (singular) and search-results.tpl.php (lists). You should be able to remove/add anything you like.